# URL gets changes after submit

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do Price Low to high and High to low sorting from google sheet that is integrated sucessfully in my website. All data, including pricing, is showing correctly.
I made the sort function, but whenever I do Low to high or high to low sorting, URL gets changed and take me wrong category.

For example, I am on page:

```
https://example.com/view-all-products.php?category=Baby+%26+Toddler+Toys
```

and when I do price sorting, after page refresh it takes me to this url

```
https://example.com/view-all-products.php?category=stuffed+%26+plush+toys&sort=asc
```

Category gets changed after page submit.

There is no .htaccess file in my project and I am not doing any url-rewrite

This is code on index.php page which takes me to view-all-products.php page for the selected category that I chose

```
<a href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '" class="btn btn-whited btn-hover-primary text-capitalize view-all-button">View All</a>
```

This is view-all-products.php code

```
<div class="shop-top-bar-right mb-4">
    <h4 class="title me-2">Sort By: </h4>
    <div class="shop-short-by">
        <form method="GET" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($category); ?>">
            <select class="nice-select" name="sort" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="asc">Price - Low To High</option>
                <option value="desc">Price - High To Low</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Shop Top Bar Right End -->

</div>
<!--shop toolbar end-->

<!-- Shop Wrapper Start -->
<?php
    // Check if the 'category' query parameter is set
    if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $category = $_GET['category'];
        $category = trim(urldecode($category));
    
        // Filter products for the specified category
        $filteredProducts = [];
        foreach ($values as $row) {
            if (
                isset($row[0]) && isset($row[1]) && isset($row[2]) && isset($row[3]) && isset($row[4])
                && trim($row[2]) === $category // Check if the category matches
            ) {
                $productTitle = '<b>(' . $row[0] . ') ' . $row[1] . '</b>';
                $productPrice = 'PKR ' . $row[3];
                $productImage = '';
                if (isset($row[8])) {
                    $productImage = $row[8];
                }
                $filteredProducts[] = [
                    'image' => $productImage,
                    'name' => $productTitle,
                    'price' => $productPrice,
                ];
            }
        }
        
        $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'asc';

        if ($sort === 'asc') {
            // Sort products from low to high based on price
            usort($filteredProducts, function ($a, $b) {
                $priceA = (int) $a['price'];
                $priceB = (int) $b['price'];
                return $priceA - $priceB;
            });
        } elseif ($sort === 'desc') {
            // Sort products from high to low based on price
            usort($filteredProducts, function ($a, $b) {
                $priceA = (int) $a['price'];
                $priceB = (int) $b['price'];
                return $priceB - $priceA;
            });
        }
    
        // Pagination settings
        $itemsPerPage = 60;
        $currentPage = isset($_GET['page']) ? max(1, intval($_GET['page'])) : 1;
        $totalItems = count($filteredProducts);
        $totalPages = ceil($totalItems / $itemsPerPage);
    
        // Calculate the start and end indexes for the current page
        $startIndex = ($currentPage - 1) * $itemsPerPage;
        $endIndex = min($startIndex + $itemsPerPage - 1, $totalItems - 1);
    
        // Display the category name and total product count
        echo '<div class="shop-top-bar-left mb-4">';
        echo '<div class="shop-top-show">';
        echo '<span style="font-size: 24px; font-weight:900">' . $category . '</span> <span style="font-size: 24px;"> - ' . $totalItems . ' items</span>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    
        // Display the products for the current page
        echo '<div class="row shop_wrapper grid_3">';
        for ($i = $startIndex; $i <= $endIndex; $i++) {
            $product = $filteredProducts[$i];
            echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 product">';
            echo '<div class="product-inner">';
            echo '<div class="thumb">';
            echo '<img class="first-image" src="' . $product['image'] . '" alt="Product" />';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="content">';
            echo '<h5 class="title">' . $product['name'] . '</h5>';
            echo '<span class="price">' . $product['price'] . '</span>';
            // Add To Cart button
            echo '<div class="add-cart-btn mt-3">';
            echo '<button class="btn btn-primary  text-capitalize add-to-cart">Add To Cart</button>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    
        // Display pagination
        echo '<div class="shop-top-bar-right mb-4">';
        echo '<nav>';
        echo '<ul class="pagination">';
        if ($currentPage > 1) {
            echo '<li class="page-item">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '&page=' . ($currentPage - 1) . '&sort=' . $sort . '" aria-label="Previous">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li class="page-item disabled">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="#" aria-label="Previous">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        for ($page = 1; $page <= $totalPages; $page++) {
            if ($page == $currentPage) {
                echo '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">' . $page . '</a></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '&page=' . $page . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $page . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        if ($currentPage < $totalPages) {
            echo '<li class="page-item">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '&page=' . ($currentPage + 1) . '&sort=' . $sort . '" aria-label="Next">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li class="page-item disabled">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="#" aria-label="Next">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</nav>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'Category not specified.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your sorting form stores the category in `<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($category); ?>">` so it can re-use it when the sorting form is submitted. But where does `$category` come from in that part of the code? We can't see how you've defined that. It's before you wrote `$category = $_GET['category'];` to fetch it from the URL.

Comment: Category is coming from index.php page, from this code i have written above also

<a href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '" class="btn btn-whited btn-hover-primary text-capitalize view-all-button">View All</a>

and then i am getting the Category on next page

Comment: does the form submission and sorting trigger a new database query? It is unclear where, amon other things, the variable `$values` is derived. You use that in a `foreach` loop

Comment: `Category is coming from index.php`...not in your sorting form, as far as we can see. Read my comment again. The `$category` variable in _this_ script isn't defined or populated before then as far as we can tell.

Comment: no databse query. i am fetching from google sheets. everything is showing correctly from google sheets.

Comment: Adyson i got your point, but i am trying from 4 hours. What can i do in this code to make it work, can you please guide me

Comment: As @Adyson said, you should initialize first your $category before using it in an input.

Comment: I tried as Adyson said, but same issue

<?php

if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['category']);
    $category = trim(urldecode($category));
} else {
    echo 'ERROR: category not exist !';
}

?>

Comment: If it's not working as you wanted, then try debugging.  Most simple approach for debugging is to var_dump the variable and exit after the var_dump. In your case try putting and moving moving this line<?php var_dump($category); exit; ?> in your code and see if it displays what you want.

Comment: If you follow my suggestion, the same as in Hanif's answer below, then the form will contain the correct value - here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/9J9vo . And if we put that into a HTML-aware environment - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/enrs6djv/, we can see (by using the browser's Console and Network tools) that when you select an option it correctly submits to a URL with parameters `?category=Baby%2B%2526%2BToddler%2BToys&sort=desc`. So the issue is not there I don't think. Go through your code carefully and try to provide us with a [mre] of the issue. It may take a bit of time to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your code, hope it's working as you need

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['category']);
    $category = urldecode(trim($category));
} else {
    echo 'ERROR: category not exist !';
}

?>
<div class="shop-top-bar-right mb-4">
    <h4 class="title me-2">Sort By: </h4>
    <div class="shop-short-by">
        <form method="GET" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?= urlencode($category); ?>">
            <select class="nice-select" name="sort" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="asc">Price - Low To High</option>
                <option value="desc">Price - High To Low</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Shop Top Bar Right End -->

</div>
<!--shop toolbar end-->

<!-- Shop Wrapper Start -->
<?php

// Check if the 'category' query parameter is set
    if ($category != '') {
    
        // Filter products for the specified category
        $filteredProducts = [];
        foreach ($values as $row) {
            if (
                isset($row[0]) && isset($row[1]) && isset($row[2]) && isset($row[3]) && isset($row[4])
                && trim($row[2]) === $category // Check if the category matches
            ) {
                $productTitle = '<b>(' . $row[0] . ') ' . $row[1] . '</b>';
                $productPrice = 'PKR ' . $row[3];
                $productImage = '';
                if (isset($row[8])) {
                    $productImage = $row[8];
                }
                $filteredProducts[] = [
                    'image' => $productImage,
                    'name' => $productTitle,
                    'price' => $productPrice,
                ];
            }
        }
        
        $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'asc';

        if ($sort === 'asc') {
            // Sort products from low to high based on price
            usort($filteredProducts, function ($a, $b) {
                $priceA = (int) $a['price'];
                $priceB = (int) $b['price'];
                return $priceA - $priceB;
            });
        } elseif ($sort === 'desc') {
            // Sort products from high to low based on price
            usort($filteredProducts, function ($a, $b) {
                $priceA = (int) $a['price'];
                $priceB = (int) $b['price'];
                return $priceB - $priceA;
            });
        }
    
        // Pagination settings
        $itemsPerPage = 60;
        $currentPage = isset($_GET['page']) ? max(1, intval($_GET['page'])) : 1;
        $totalItems = count($filteredProducts);
        $totalPages = ceil($totalItems / $itemsPerPage);
    
        // Calculate the start and end indexes for the current page
        $startIndex = ($currentPage - 1) * $itemsPerPage;
        $endIndex = min($startIndex + $itemsPerPage - 1, $totalItems - 1);
    
        // Display the category name and total product count
        echo '<div class="shop-top-bar-left mb-4">';
        echo '<div class="shop-top-show">';
        echo '<span style="font-size: 24px; font-weight:900">' . $category . '</span> <span style="font-size: 24px;"> - ' . $totalItems . ' items</span>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    
        // Display the products for the current page
        echo '<div class="row shop_wrapper grid_3">';
        for ($i = $startIndex; $i <= $endIndex; $i++) {
            $product = $filteredProducts[$i];
            echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 product">';
            echo '<div class="product-inner">';
            echo '<div class="thumb">';
            echo '<img class="first-image" src="' . $product['image'] . '" alt="Product" />';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="content">';
            echo '<h5 class="title">' . $product['name'] . '</h5>';
            echo '<span class="price">' . $product['price'] . '</span>';
            // Add To Cart button
            echo '<div class="add-cart-btn mt-3">';
            echo '<button class="btn btn-primary  text-capitalize add-to-cart">Add To Cart</button>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    
        // Display pagination
        echo '<div class="shop-top-bar-right mb-4">';
        echo '<nav>';
        echo '<ul class="pagination">';
        if ($currentPage > 1) {
            echo '<li class="page-item">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '&page=' . ($currentPage - 1) . '&sort=' . $sort . '" aria-label="Previous">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li class="page-item disabled">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="#" aria-label="Previous">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        for ($page = 1; $page <= $totalPages; $page++) {
            if ($page == $currentPage) {
                echo '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">' . $page . '</a></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '&page=' . $page . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $page . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        if ($currentPage < $totalPages) {
            echo '<li class="page-item">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="view-all-products.php?category=' . urlencode($category) . '&page=' . ($currentPage + 1) . '&sort=' . $sort . '" aria-label="Next">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li class="page-item disabled">';
            echo '<a class="page-link rounded-0" href="#" aria-label="Next">';
            echo '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</nav>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'Category not specified.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: i tried this already. Still it takes me to wrong category url as i specified above

Comment: and with your complete code
always wrong url is being called
view-all-products.php?category=stuffed+%26+plush+toys&sort=asc

Comment: Remove "urldecode" and "urlencode" from whole code and try again. We already check $category in first place.

Comment: did that. not working.

Comment: Is it possible to see your query code ? Because this code looks good, and it seems problem accrued by something else.

Comment: Here is have explained well and shown the scenario completely. By applying the code of Hanif totally

https://www.loom.com/share/28689cec931f4c848c8471be0b84397d?sid=b6f2c105-01db-48f5-bf3e-f137785b8b9c

Comment: @SZ100 FYI: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**"_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). An external video won't, by itself, be accepted as a valid example on Stackoverflow. You need to edit your question too.

Comment: Hanif, you can download both index and view-all-products files here
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0b033f01b46ce0d8b2ed4948f68fdcdf20231006091800/e1c3ab?utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_05&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&trk=TRN_TDL_05

Comment: I have clarified thoroughly what i want to achieve and what i have tried and what error i am having. 
there is nothing that i have talked out of scope.

Comment: @SZ100 your question _will_ be closed down as off-topic if you don't edit it, and provide the relevant material there. 3rd-party links are _not_ considered acceptable. We are not a helpdesk. The idea is to preserve information for future readers too. Stackoverflow cannot guarantee that content on other sites will still be available in future.

Comment: i don't know which part in my question is irrelevent or where i haven't produced the error or what i failed to tell. 
If there is, i will love to remove and edit my question. As far as i know, i completely described what issue i am facing, what i have tried

Comment: @SZ100 It's quite simple: you're posting links to videos and code on other sites which appear to be additional to what's in your question. Any information you want to provide us with needs to go directly into your question. That is how Stackoverflow operates - you can read the guidance I provided. At the moment, we have shown you how to fix the problem you're having, _as it currently is presented in your question_. If you're saying that doesn't fully solve it, you need to change your question so it demonstrates your current issue.

Comment: you are right. Hanfi asked me to show him my code, i just made a video that contains the problem only with the solutions that are given me here. I just applied the codes, made a video to show and thats it. 
what i tried before, is already in my question, the complete code which i have tried. if video is issue, i will delete it

Comment: @sz100 you can add some images from video to your question. That will be helpful and usable for me or others.

Comment: Dear Hanfi, i have shared the code and video is 5 min long. Trust me, i am only addressing the issue, nothing else. Trying to be more clear

Comment: @SZ100 `what i tried before, is already in my question, the complete code which i have tried` OK... but now you're saying that the fix Hanif and I have provided does not work, even though I have demonstrated in my other comments that it generates the correct URL. So then _presumably_ there is another issue which is not visible from the code currently available to us in your post. Either that, or you did not apply the fix correctly.

Comment: There is no other page in my site currently. no htaaccess file, no url redirect or rewrites. There are only 2 pages and i have shared code of both files. 
furthermore, here is https://primemall.intellectsofts.com/index.php

Comment: @SZ100 I watched the video anyway. I agree with you there should be no reason to remove urlencode and urldecode, on that I do not agree with hanif. But the rest of the code in this answer should be correct. If it's not working for you then we can only assume something else is happening, or that you are not executing the code you have edited. I can see you are trying to edit code in your live site. This makes it a lot harder for you to debug and test it. Why do you not have a local development environment with a copy of your code and database where you can do faster and easier debugging?

Comment: @SZ100 or perhaps it's better for simplicity if you follow the version I provided in the demo link: https://3v4l.org/9J9vo rather than the code here. It is slightly different, i.e. not changing any of the urlencode or urldecode usage.

Comment: actually i have currently xamp 7.4 and lots of site are running in 7.4 environment. this site only required php 8.1.0. thats why i put it live. 
And on the demo link, when i hard code the category as in the demo link, then it diesn't load the wrong category url after page submit.

Comment: this site doen't require any database. It is directly connected and integrating Google Sheets

Comment: @SZ100 ok but you can still have a local 8.1 environment to test with. Never develop and test on a live site!

Comment: yes for that, need to install another xamp version. but apologies, issue persits

Comment: @SZ100 Only another PHP version would be needed, not the whole of XAMPP. Or you could use a VM, or Docker, or anything like that.

Comment: @SZ100 Anyway, in your video at 3:29 I can see that regardless of the url-encoding issues, when you click the sort button it changes the "category" variable in the URL to something completely different. If you have implemented the changes as per my demo (please double-check) then there is simply no way it could change the URL to an entirely different one. (I proved this with the JSFiddle demo too https://jsfiddle.net/enrs6djv/). So _either_ you're not testing with the code you're showing us _or_ there is something extra going on - e.g. some JS or other code causing an extra redirect

Comment: @SZ100 It would be instructive to a) examine the source code of view_all_products.php in your browser after you load it initially. Check what's actually in the `<input type="hidden" name="category" value` area...does the URL there look like what you expected? And then...open your browser's Network tool (press F12 and go to the Network tab in the developer area). After that, set the sort option. Then watch the Network tool. Does the browser make a request to the expected URL? If so, what is the response which comes back? Does it also make a request to any other URLs which you _didn't_ expect?

Comment: i did tried your demo too seriouly. When i put this line
$_GET["category"] = 'Baby+%26+Toddler+Toys';
then url doesn't change. 
but the thing is, i can't put static category name as there are many categories.

Comment: when the view products page loads initially, 

https://ibb.co/2Nxrqyv

After sort and page refresh

https://ibb.co/R2vdgtn

Comment: Could you find any clue?

Comment: @SZ100 `When i put this line $_GET["category"] = 'Baby+%26+Toddler+Toys';`...i thought it was clear from what I wrote that this was just a simulation for that demo instead of using what's really in the URL. You aren't supposed to copy that bit into your real code

Comment: As you can see in this image, the value of input::hidden::category, already manipulated. So the problem is, someplace in your code, the value of $category will change incorrectly. Try to use $_GET['category'] to input::hidden::category directly. https://ibb.co/J2bp4zW

Comment: @SZ100 Anyway I just visited your site right now. Look at `view-source:https://www.primemall.intellectsofts.com/view-all-products.php?category=Baby+%26+Toddler+Toys` . Here is what I found in there:  `<form method="GET" action=""><input type="hidden" name="category" value="Water Toys">` So clearly _something_ is putting "Water Toys" into that "value", even when that isn't the category in the URL. That is not being done by the code I provided for you. This is what I am trying to say. There is _something else_ which _you haven't shown us_ which is manipulating that data. Do some digging.

Comment: @SZ100 At a guess could there be some code in `main_nav.php` which is causing a problem? I notice you have `<?php include("include/main_nav.php");?>` in your code, which comes in between where you are (now) setting the $category, and where you are outputting the sort form with the hidden category field.